# sed from java gives error

Tags: java, sed, exec

I am trying to use sed to replace the spaces in a file with newlines. This is part of a test suite that needs to be automated, and one of the tools the test suite requires, outputs to a file a space separated list, that needs to be newline separated.

The code I am running looks like this:

```
  exec = String.format("sed -i 's/ /\\n/g\' %s", filename);
  Process p1 = run.exec(exec);
  results = getOutput(p1.getErrorStream());
  p.waitFor();
```

the file remains unchanged and results contains this: `"sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command:`'' "`

the value of exec is: `sed -i 's/ /\n/g' /absolute/path/to/file.out` and if I run the command from the command line, it works.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your first two lines with:

```
Process p1 = run.exec(new String[]{"sed", "-i", "s/ /\\n/g", filename});
```

What's going on here:  You're trying to call the one-arg version of `Runtime.exec()`.  This doesn't parse your command string into arguments honoring single-quoted or double-quoted strings like a "real" shell would - instead, it just splits on whitespace:

> [T]he command string is broken into tokens using a `StringTokenizer` created by the call `new StringTokenizer(command)` with no further modification of the character categories. ([Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.io.File%29))

To get the behavior you expect, you'll need to break your command line into arguments yourself, and pass them in as an array.

Comment: I actually figured this out about an hour ago (before checking back here) but didn't know the reason. Thanks!